# How can I fix this broken connector piece on my Symmons shower Knob?

Tags: plumbing, repair, water, faucet, installation

I was trying to get the knob off so I could potentially increase the amount of hot water getting mixed and it seemed to be coming off nicely but then snapped. By nicely, I mean it was a steady process; the thing was rusted/stuck on so bad I'm not sure it would have been possible to get off without breaking it.

[image: knob]
[image: faceplate]

I can turn the water on and off with pliers but that's not ideal obviously. Primarily I need some instruction on how to get this existing set up replaced with something new that has good hot water management. I see some screws but am not sure if I should do anything else without some guidance as to what it does (the ominous left only screw).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a link to the [Installation, Operation & Service Instructions (PDF)](http://www.symmons.com/~/media/Files/Symmons/Products/Visu%20Temp%20With%20Clear%20Vue/1%201000VT_Installation.pdf) that contain an exploded diagram of all the parts of your valve.

[image]
<sup>*Click for larger view*</sup>

If you scroll down you even get detailed instructions about servicing the valve, how to order parts, and troubleshooting for common problems (like not getting enough hot water).

Comment: I don't think that's the right diagram? It's similar but not exact anyways.